# Range object in functions

Tags: excel, vba

When I use below user defined function in Excel sheet, I got `"#VALUE!"`. 
As `Match1` line produced right value, I think there is a bug in the other lines.

```
Public Function FVLAND(Date1, Date2)
    Dim Match1 As Integer
    Dim Offset1 As Range
    Match1 = Application.Match(Year(Date1 + 365), Range("Table1[Year]"))
    Set Offset1 = Application.Offset(Range("Table1[[#Headers],[SW]]"), Match1, 0, (Year(Date2) - Year(Date1)), 1)
    FVLAND = Application.FVSchedule(1, Offset1)
End Function
```

Comment: Try worksheetfunction.FVschedule and see if it helps

Comment: If these are all built-in functions, then what is the point of creating a UDF for it? The built-in functions will perform better.

Comment: From MSDN on FVSchedule -The values in schedule can be numbers or blank cells; any other value produces the #VALUE! error value for FVSCHEDULE. Blank cells are taken as zeros (no interest).  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821232.aspx